# List the value of a Subscribe in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that connects to another sibling component. From that, I made a service so that it is possible to make this communication. So far so good. The problem is that I can not retrieve the values ​​of the subscribe that is inside a component to be able to list.

table.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from './../service/shared.service';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-component',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss']
})

export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  private value: any;
  private data: any;
  private filteredValues = [];
  private message: string = 'Utilize os filtros acima para exibir especialidades, ou';

  constructor(private service: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    /* Get JSON results */
    this.service.getApi().subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;      
    })

    /* Filter click button */
    this.service.currentValue.subscribe(value => {
      this.filteredValues = [];
      this.value = value;
      if(this.data !== undefined){
        for(let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++){
          if(this.data[i].codeId === this.value[0].code && this.data[i].rowId === this.value[0].row){
            this.filteredValues.push(this.data[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    })
    //nothing appears on the console
    console.log('this.filteredValues', this.filteredValues);
  }

}
```

shared.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

const URL = '../../assets/api.json';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
currentValue = this.messageSource.asObservable();

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

changeMessage(message: any) {
  this.messageSource.next(message)
}

getApi(){
  return this.http.get(URL);
}

}
```

I wanted to consume this filteredValues ​​array, however, it does not show me anything. I know it's related to subscribe, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Have you verified that each of your `subscribe` methods are executing?

Comment: Excuse me. I did not understand you. I'm new to Angular+, but in console.log I see everything I need, but I can not print in HTML

Comment: where and when did you call service function `changeMessage`?

Comment: How are you trying to "print" it in the HTML?

Comment: @Pengyy in click button
  private filter(){
    this.data.changeMessage([{code: parseInt(this.codeFilter), row: parseInt(this.rowFilter), name: this.nameFilter}])
  }

Comment: Then add this click function, maybe also your template about the button to your question.

Comment: @Daniel W Strimpel
ngFor="let item of filteredValues"

Comment: I’m unsure if this is related or not since I can’t see your html but you put ngFor...it should be *ngFor. If that isn’t it, html would be helpful since that seems like where the issue may be.

Comment: @DanielSwater can you add `HTML` ?

Comment: The problem is not HTML. I edited the file table.component.ts